# TypeScript type for reduce

Tags: typescript

How would you declare a type for this properly?

```js
interface MediaQueryProps {
  [key: string]: number;
}

const size: MediaQueryProps = {
  small: 576,
  medium: 768,
  large: 992,
  extra: 1200
};

export default Object.keys(size).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur] = `(min-width: ${size[cur]}px)`;

  return acc;
}, {});
```

`acc[cur]` is complaining because

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'
```

Is there any way I can declare a type for this without using any?

Comment: Though unrelated to the exact question, might be helpful for people coming here from Google. There is an outstanding bug in TypeScript with inferring the type of `reduce`'s accumulator and return value: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25454

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you want the accumulator value to be indexable by `string`, `Record<string, string>` should do the trick. You can pass this as the type argument to `reduce`

```
interface MediaQueryProps {
  [key: string]: number;
}

const size: MediaQueryProps = {
  small: 576,
  medium: 768,
  large: 992,
  extra: 1200
};

export default Object.keys(size).reduce<Record<string, string>>((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur] = `(min-width: ${size[cur]}px)`;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQCbDgRQK7QCeAClAPYAOAzsgN4BQyyA2gNYSEBcyVYUoAcwC63EHgC2AI2gBuegF969BGRC8ewAF4Ru6LLgJQS5asgC8dRj3FwANre4BWAOwA2ADRXxmYBO5uADk8mWzgoAR1kAE4ogCZg5AgADz44bgBGWIAGLIU5emSKMigwZAwIeDxbUoB5SQArCAQwADp2QioACiotCABKFqhMPCQAHgAlJuKMUd5+EAF3Hj5BAD5Vzs7EBCWEPCg+81XLJm3mPaghc2QAA07xUABaAHdgDDAAC24AEloe7XO+yE8goST6NzkTCGYH2IGQ2zk8iWtHkfRkQA)

Comment: const a = Object.keys(size).....

console.log(a.small); ??? how to get link for that?

Answer (score 9):

With TypeScript 4.1 you can also take advantage of [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) with `as` type casting. [TypeScript Playground Link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQCbDgRQK7QCeAClAPYAOAzsgN4BQyyA2gNYSEBcyVYUoAcwC63EHgC2AI2gBuegF969BGRC8ewAF4oAvHUY9xcADbHuAVgDsANgA0B8ZmATuNgBz2mxuFAERuAJwBAEyeyBAAHnxw3ACMwQAMCQrIcDQqamByyqrqjli4BFCEANIcNHoA8pIAVhAIYAB07IRUABRUWhAAlKk0AIJQUHCEADwtZDDIYIQUEJMa2gB82Rl5ToXQwBAVyPnY%20ERlrY1QmHhIbW2ICLbICHhQvTpL%20kw3zA9QQsh6AAZtcSgAC0AHdgBgwAALbgAElonW0n0eQnkFAi3T%202SYZzAjxAqQQCDk8jutHkfWQACV6mQoBhRn94RMpjM5gtERB5H87rx%20CABEtutlIhQ6WBkBgIPA8MYJftNvwdjIgA)

```
// .ts
interface MediaQueryProps {
  [key: string]: number;
}

const size = {
  small: 576,
  medium: 768,
  large: 992,
  extra: 1200
} as const;

const mediaQueryKeys = Object.keys(size) as Array<keyof typeof size>;

const mediaQueries = mediaQueryKeys.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur] = `(min-width: ${size[cur]}px)`;

  return acc;
}, {} as Record<`${keyof typeof size}`, string>);

export default mediaQueries;

// d.ts
declare const mediaQueries: Record<"small" | "medium" | "large" | "extra", string>;
export default mediaQueries;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do it like this using `Record` and `keyof`:

```
export default Object.keys(size).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur] = `(min-width: ${size[cur]}px)`;

  return acc;
}, {} as Record<keyof MediaQueryProps, string>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Approved answear uses only string type, but I wanted more accurate types, so this is my approach:

```
type Breakpoints = {
  small: number;
  medium: number;
  large: number;
  extra: number;
};

const size: Breakpoints = {
  small: 576,
  medium: 768,
  large: 992,
  extra: 1200
};

// Type of entry after Object.entries() is used
type BreakpointEntry = [keyof Breakpoints, Breakpoints[keyof Breakpoints]];

// Generic helper to make all of the properties' types: string | undefined
type Stringify<T> = { [key in keyof T]?: string };

// Override Object interface for custom Object.entries():
interface CustomObject extends ObjectConstructor {
  entries<K extends keyof Breakpoints, T>(
    o: { [s in K]: T } | ArrayLike<T>
  ): [K, T][];
}

// Let's use this interface now:
const obj: CustomObject = Object;

export default obj
  .entries(size)
  .reduce<Stringify<Breakpoint>>((acc, cur: BreakpointEntry) => {
    const [key, value] = cur;
    acc[key] = `(min-width: ${value}px)`;

    return acc;
  }, {});
```