# Proper type for reducer's accumulator

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I describe `result` and `acc` type for the following code?

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;

const result = arr.reduce((acc, item, idx) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
    [item]: idx,
  }
}, {});
```

Depends on an iteration `acc` can be:

1. {}
2. a: number
3. a: number, b: number
4. a: number, b: number, c: number

First I used this code:

```
type MyResult = Record<typeof arr[number], number>; //  
type MyAcc = Partial<MyResult>;
```

But it's incorrect:

```
  Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=22#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcjpgNDTAIzwOEwF14IZRIoBuAKEduhgQFMIBXAGygBcMALIBPAEpc%20sNIgQA6TgBNuwDgAp1cYMCFiAgjvwBLKBwC2JpQA8AlKgB8MAN6MAkJyjcEYF%205gw8kHawLiMAQHophbkQsY2YQEAvoxJ%20M5JtkyMUKIADhwiElL8qDCSoAhKADy5BSAAZvBI6GDc5oQcCOT4bR1dDkx1hQY6ZQAKiFDGcLzVYpI8-IOMQA)

Comment: There is a nice explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379778/typescript-type-for-reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
type ArrayItemType<A extends ReadonlyArray<any>> = A[number];

const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;

type KeyIndexes = Record<ArrayItemType<typeof arr>, number>;

const result = arr.reduce((acc, item, idx) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
    [item]: idx,
  }
}, {} as KeyIndexes);
```

`KeyIndexes` is effectively:

```
{
  a: number,
  b: number,
  c: number
}
```

...as you can see [at this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAksCBbAKuCAeGKCAD3QDsATAZygCUJEKB7MgGxHiRD0TJAD5+UALywA2mQCuGAEYQ4AXQDcAKBUBjFlWBRECEVDEByREYA0UIzPOX1Rhbpqay21StCQoAaQipKJCBpRek04CgIEZDRMHEg8DwgmADNdBH4LKVl5fjdnbSg4QMlWHVE9OAA6QopJdQgACnrEdXULAEt0DHaKYgBKESEAbxUoUYKIYEk4MihhsbGKxebWkbGxDswFAC4oNp6zVYBfFUOLQcPHb18Uf2JA3tUgA)

I realize the objection that *technically* the initializer and accumulator are not this type at all stages of the reduction, but TypeScript really doesn't have a way of figuring out how a partial result will become the full result, so you'll need casting at some point anyway.

**Update**

If you *really* care that the accumulator is of a different type than the result, you can adjust the types accordingly, but you'll have to do some more ugly casting:

```
type ArrayItemType<A extends ReadonlyArray<any>> = A[number];

const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;

type KeyIndexes = Record<ArrayItemType<typeof arr>, number>;

const result = arr.reduce((acc: Partial<KeyIndexes>, item, idx) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
    [item]: idx,
  }
}, {}) as KeyIndexes;
```

(see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAksCBbAKuCAeGKCAD3QDsATAZygCUJEKB7MgGxHiRD0TJAD5+UALywA2mQCuGAEYQ4AXQDcAKBUBjFlWBRECEVDEByREYA0UIzPOX1Rhbpqay21StCQoAaQipKJCBpRek04CgIEZDRMHEg8DwgmADNdBH4LKVl5fjdnbSg4QMlWHVE9OAA6QopJdQgACnrEdXUALigABT1gAEtEVjwfPwoAqnSoHvQMCx6KYgBKESEAbxUodYKIYEk4MihVjY2K4+b1MzWNsUnMBXbZ4nP1gF8VJ4tlp8XEGiGUf2JAqogA))

Comment: Thank you, but it looks like broken. Fields `a | b | c` marked as existing ones in every iteration, so I'm able to do this (str 8):

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAksCBbAKuCAeGKCAD3QDsATAZygCUJEKB7MgGxHiRD0TJAD5+UALywA2mQCuGAEYQ4AXQDcAKBUBjFlWBRECEVDEByREYA0UIzPOX1Rhbpqay21StCQoAaQipKJCBpRek04CgIEZDRMHEg8DwgmADNdBH4LKVl5fjdnbSg4QMlWHVE9OAA6QopJdQgACnrEdXULAEt0DHaKYgBKESEAbxUoUag8nQwQADlpOTgALihM+YNm9QrEKABqXRaKmVUxqBGxwuBJODIoYePRiof1s1PRsQ7MBSW2nufRgF8VH8LIM-o5vL4UP5iIFeqogA)

Comment: Yeah, like I said, TypeScript doesn't have a way to differentiate between the partial return value while reducing and the final value. See my upcoming update (in short, if you really care about the fact that the accumulator has a different type than the final result, you can type it as such, but then you'll have to cast the final result).

Comment: Thank you again :)