# How to make typesafe environment variable loader

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm tring to make a dynamic .env loader and validator. Im using envalid package and then a custom function that loads the environmet variables based on parameter input.

I have a class with property `requiredEnvs = [{ name: 'DATABASE_URL', type: str() }]` and then I'm calling my loadEnv function `const env = loadEnv(requiredEnvs)`. Now I should be able to access DATABASE_URL on `env.DATABASE_URL` and also have intellisense.

This is my `loadEnv` function

```
const loadEnv = (envRequirements: EnvironmentVariable[])=> {
    const obj = envRequirements.reduce((result, curr) => {
        result[curr.name]  = curr.type
        return result; 
    }, {})
    const env = cleanEnv(process.env, obj)
    return env
}
```

However, in `loadEnv` function I'm getting an error saying "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'" and I think this is the main source of my problem.

I have tried settings `curr.name` as so many types but i have no idea. I think I have to use typescript dynamic typing features, but I'm not that experienced yet so I would really like some help, thank you.

Here is the repo to replicate the problem: https://github.com/davidprokopec/typescript-loadEnvProblem

here should be a [playground](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/node-playground-forked-vdkyvo?file=%2Fsrc%2Futil%2FloadEnv.ts&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A8%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A1%2C%22startColumn%22%3A8%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A1%7D%5D) ready

Comment: Can we get a [mre] in the form of a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/Q)?

Comment: You don't provide any annotation to your reduce initial value, so it has type `{}`, i.e. an object with no properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript type for reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379778/typescript-type-for-reduce)

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.reduce()` has a generic signature. When you don't supply any arguments for the type parameters, it infers the type of the object you are trying to create from the final `initialValue` argument, which is currently `{}`.

Since inferring the type from the value `{}` gets you the type of `{}`, which is 'an object that never has any keys or values', typescript is producing an error because you are trying to then assign values to keys that shouldn't exist.

The solution to your problem is to supply an appropriate generic type parameter for reduce.

```
const obj = envRequirements.reduce<Record<string, string>>((result, curr) => {
  result[curr.name] = curr.type;
  return result;
}, {});
```

I've chosen `Record<string, string>` here because I don't know what type you want to assign to the value. You might be able to grab it from 'EnvironmentVariable' by doing `Record<string, EnvironmentVariable['type']>`